# A problem in addView()in ConstraintLayout, don't get the required result

Tags: java, android

The ( else ) part working properly, but the problem is in ( if ) part when adding the view again to the ConstraintLayout.

I want something like this.

[image]

But I get this which is not what I want.

[image]

```
        public class ChecklistChildViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBox;
        ImageView delete, edit, move;
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

        ChecklistChildViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_child);
            delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_child);
            edit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_child);
            move = itemView.findViewById(R.id.move_child);
            constraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.constraint_child);

        }

        public void updateVisibility(boolean isEnableDelete){

            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lpCheckBox = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) checkBox.getLayoutParams();
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lpDelete = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) delete.getLayoutParams();
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lpEdit = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) edit.getLayoutParams();

            if (isEnableDelete) {



                constraintLayout.removeView(move);
                constraintLayout.addView(delete);
                constraintLayout.addView(edit);
                lpDelete.endToEnd = R.id.constraint_child;
                lpDelete.startToEnd = R.id.edit_child;

                lpEdit.startToEnd = R.id.checkbox_child;
                lpEdit.endToStart = R.id.delete_child;

                delete.setLayoutParams(lpDelete);
                edit.setLayoutParams(lpEdit);
            }

            else {

                constraintLayout.removeView(delete);
                constraintLayout.removeView(edit);

                lpCheckBox.endToStart = R.id.move_child;
                lpCheckBox.startToStart = R.id.constraint_child;

                checkBox.setLayoutParams(lpCheckBox);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know where the problem is. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to alternate between having a "move" icon or having the "edit" and "delete" icons it is much easier to just toggle the view visibilities between `GONE` or `VISIBLE`. When views are changed to `GONE` the connected constraints are updated automatically by the ConstraintLayout, you don't have to do that manually.

For example:

```java
public void updateVisibility(boolean isEnableDelete){
    if (isEnableDelete) {
        delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        move.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        move.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

with a row XML that looks like this, where the three icons are in a row on the right side and the CheckBox is set to fill the space from start to the start of the icons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/edit"
        tools:text="Some CheckBox"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit_24"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/delete"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/move"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/move"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_graphic_eq_24"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Setting this to alternate between every other row (as an example) gives this:

[image: alternating row icons]